# Switching between Light and Dark mode without manual style

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-dark-theme

I write an App with Xamarin.forms, and I want to change between light and dark mode.
I want to have a switch to change between the two modes.

So each time the switch is toggled I set App.Current.UserAppTheme=OSAppTheme.Dark or App.Current.UserAppTheme=OSAppTheme.Light.

This is set correctly as the Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged is triggered and if I check the UserAppTheme I get the correct value.
And the properties I manually set with the AppThemeBinding change. But the background for example stays the same.

If I change the Theme in the phone settings and restart the app, a different background color is shown.

So is it possible to let the OS choose the colors or do I have to create and set fixed style sheets?

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to let the OS choose the colors

Of course, you can set the colors you want.

The steps are as follows:

1.define the colors in file `App.xaml`.

For example, you can add a light color ad a dark color:

```
<Application.Resources>

        <!-- Light colors -->
        <Color x:Key="LightPageBackgroundColor">Yellow</Color>

        <!-- Dark colors -->
        <Color x:Key="DarkPageBackgroundColor">Red</Color>

</Application.Resources>
```

2.Then, in your app, you can set the BackgroundColor for ContentPage as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemThemesDemo"
             x:Class="SystemThemesDemo.Views.UserSummaryPage"
             Title="User Summary"

             BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPageBackgroundColor}}">

</ContentPage>
```

**Update:**

You can also define a global style in `App.xaml`:

```
    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage"  x:Key="MyPageStyle">

        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPageBackgroundColor}}" />
    </Style>
```

And apply it to the ContentPages you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SystemThemesDemo.Views.MyPage"
         Title="TestPage"
         
          Style="{StaticResource MyPageStyle}"
        >

 </ContentPage>
```

For more information, you can check document:[Theme an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming).

You can also check the official samples here: [SystemThemesDemo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/SystemThemesDemo)  and [ThemingDemo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/ThemingDemo).

Comment: Tanks, I know, that I can manually set the Background depending on some Binding. But the background is already different depending on the Systems dark/light mode setting, without me setting any resources.
So the question is if I can use this instead of setting every background manually?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can set background in `App.xaml` and apply it to all your pages.

Comment: You can also define a global style for your pages. For more information, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @EmilG, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.